# How to efficiently display objects related to specific foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models

I have separate models for authors and theses and the author model has a foreign key to the thesis model. My question is how can I efficiently display the authors for each thesis?

This is my models.py for the author and thesis

```
class thesisDB(Model):
    thesis_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    adviser = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Authors(Model):
    thesis = models.ForeignKey(thesisDB, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_initial = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True, validators=[initial_validator])
```

I am currently doing this method where I loop through all the authors and match their foreign key id to the thesis id in thesisdb model so I can display the right authors for each thesis.

```
{% for post in thesis_details %}
<p class="m-0"><i class="bi bi-person pe-1"></i>Authors:
    {% for author in authors %}
       {% if author.thesis.thesis_id == post.thesis_id %}
        <span class="me-1">{{author.first_name}} {{author.middle_initial}} {{author.last_name}}</span>
       {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't seem efficient. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Django provides built-in support for related objects. You can use `_set`.

```
{% for post in thesis_details %}
<p class="m-0"><i class="bi bi-person pe-1"></i>Authors:
    {% for author in post.authors_set.all %}
        <span class="me-1">{{author.first_name}} {{author.middle_initial}} {{author.last_name}}</span>
    {% endfor %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Read more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/relations/